# How to get a thumbnail view in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, stable-diffusion

I'm running a gpu pod on runpod.io to run stable diffusion. I've been generating many images using SD and these images are automatically saved in the outputs folder on the server which is accessible using a jupyter Notebook.

I want to view the photos in that folder in a thumbnail view so I can delete the ones I don't need instead of opening each file to see what it is.

Is it possible and if so how I can I do this?

I'm not sure what to do, I don't have any experience with jupyter notebook to understand it even at a beginner level

Comment: Did you try adapting [here](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/main/docs/source/examples/Image%20Browser.ipynb) or [here](https://mindtrove.info/jupyter-tidbit-image-gallery)?

Comment: Hey Wayne, so I tried the second method but it didn’t work for me. The images are not loading. Could you me understand what needs to be adapted in that code. I’m not versed with the syntax

Comment: That is a specific & different question than you originally posted. Ideally you'd post a new question with code of what works and the part that doesn't. Comments aren't a way to move on to a new question, see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/321907/8508004).